# Jenkins Weblogic Server Deployment weblogic.management.home.localhome

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, weblogic, continuous-deployment

**Scenario**:
I try to deploy web services to weblogic server by Jenkins + weblogic deployer. 
I successfully get war files after build. 
While deploying war files I get below error in console.

**Additional descriptions**:
This is enterprise environment. Jenkins and Weblogic server are running on different servers but connetions are ok. On weblogic server there 4 applications 
my web services running on a cluster.

**Question: What is the meaning of this error? How to fix it or at least where should I concentrate? :)**

> Reason: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
>   'weblogic.management.home.localhome' didn't find subcontext 'home'.
>   Resolved 'weblogic.management' [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup
>   'weblogic.management.home.localhome' didn't find subcontext 'home'.
>   Resolved 'weblogic.management']; remaining name 'home/localhome'

[image: Console output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a NameNotFoundException when trying to lookup a resource (**weblogic.management.home.localhome**) using JNDI. The exception says that part of the name is resolved (**weblogic.management**) but that it cannot resolve the remainder (**home.localhome**).

In the Javadoc for NameNotFoundException, you'll see:

> This exception is thrown when a component of the name cannot be resolved because it is not bound.

That means that, either the subcontext information for the JNDI resourcs (home.localhome) is incorrect, or the subcontext (home.localhome) is not registered with the JNDI naming service.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/NamingException.html (superclass of the NameNotFoundException) for the exception and review the JNDI info here for configuration help: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/core/index.html

Comment: This is my error : While trying to lookup 'weblogic.management.home.localhome' didn't find subcontext 'management'. Any idea?